# Two wallets running on same keystore file?

Tags: mist, accounts

I created a wallet @ myetherwallet. I received some ethers here and it worked fine. But I didn´t understand where the ethers were at first, so I openend another wallet locally on my mac: ethereum wallet. It shows 0 ethers when I import the same keystore file I use with myetherwallet online. I bought some new ethers now, in which wallet will they show up as they are being sent to the keystore address that is used by both wallets?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A precise way to answer this would be: 
The balances will be in control of anyone who can identify himself to the network as the account holder, through a key file, for example. So you can control all your funds of your accounts wherever you add your key.

Comment: Thanks:) But whereas myetherwallet requires a pswd and then shows the correct balance of funds, "ethereum wallet" doesn´t and just shows a balance (right now 0) just with loading the keystore file.

Comment: maybe it's not fully synced yet ?